# Which object should I parse this JSON into?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am using ASP.NET C# with the JSON.net package installed. I have some JSON:

```
{
    "ROWSET": {
        "ROW": {
            "A_ONLINE_PO_COUNT": 0,
            "A_OFFLINE_PO_COUNT": 0,
            "A_NEW_MESSAGE_COUNT": 0,
            "A_PASSWORD_EXPIRE_DAYS": 9,
            "PO_REPORTS": {
                "PO_REPORTS_ROW": {
                    "PO_REPORT_PARAMETER_ID": 1575,
                    "DESCRIPTION": "TESTING SAVE"
                }
            },
            "RECV_REPORTS": "\n  ",
            "BUDGET_REPORTS": "\n  ",
            "VARIANCE_REPORTS": "\n  "
        }
    }
}
```

and was wondering what object exactly I could parse it into? If it were JavaScript, it would be easy to just stick it into a `var result` and access (for example) the Online PO Count via `result.ROWSET.ROW.A_ONLINE_PO_COUNT`.

Is there a similar way to do this in C#? I don't know which object to deserialize it into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) for generating your classes

```
public class POREPORTSROW
{
    public int PO_REPORT_PARAMETER_ID { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}

public class POREPORTS
{
    public POREPORTSROW PO_REPORTS_ROW { get; set; }
}

public class ROW
{
    public int A_ONLINE_PO_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int A_OFFLINE_PO_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int A_NEW_MESSAGE_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int A_PASSWORD_EXPIRE_DAYS { get; set; }
    public POREPORTS PO_REPORTS { get; set; }
    public string RECV_REPORTS { get; set; }
    public string BUDGET_REPORTS { get; set; }
    public string VARIANCE_REPORTS { get; set; }
}

public class ROWSET
{
    public ROW ROW { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ROWSET ROWSET { get; set; }
}
```

You can also deserialize to `dynamic` and use it like in Javascript

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.ROWSET.ROW.A_ONLINE_PO_COUNT);
```

Comment: I am using your second solution. Do you know how I can easily iterate through "PO reports?" For example, it may have more than one "PO_REPORTS_ROW". I try storing `obj.ROWSET.ROW.PO_REPORTS` into `var = reportsList` but I don't know how to iterate through it. Any tips?

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe if you cast `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to `JObject` instead of dynamic, you can use it as a dictionary with all Linq tricks. `Children` `Descendents`  etc....